# 2 error problems for simple music players

Tags: actionscript-3, text, ioerror

I have 2 Errors:
#2044: Unhandled IOErrorEvent:. text=Error #2032: Stream Error.

I tested a few times, and I have both Unhandled IOErrorEvent and Stream Error for a Music Player Scene. I found this video how to create a simple MP3 Player using actionscript 3.0,
Anyone can fix these errors?

```
    var myMusic:Sound = new Sound();
    var musicChannel: SoundChannel = new SoundChannel();
    var musicIndex: Number = 0;
    var music: Array = new Array();
    var pp: Boolean = true;
    
    music = ['Aqua Man- Guitar Remix', 'Summer Treasure Hunt Event 1', 'Summer Treasure Hunt Event 2',
        'Sizzling Heat! Splendid Summer Event', 'Brick Dive', 'Bloocheep Ocean','Dire Dire Docks Remix - Calm Waters', 
        'Dire Dire Docks Remix - Calm Waters', 'Mario Teaches Typing 2 (1996) - Underwater', 'Treasure Cove! Level 1', 
        'Treasure Cove! Level 2', 'Treasure Cove! Level 3', 'Under Pressure'];
    
    myMusic.load(new URLRequest("E:/Flash Animations/Folder 1/Games/Bit-Bot Math Voyage/Music"+[musicIndex]));
```

Comment: The most probable cause — the resulting URL is wrong, specifically **.../Music"+[musicIndex]** probably results in **.../Music0"**. You should **trace** the URL, then paste it into explorer and see, if it is indeed a valid URL to an MP3 file.

Comment: TypeError: Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert "E:/Flash Animations/Folder 1/Games/Bit-Bot Math Voyage/MusicAqua Man- Guitar Remix" to flash.net.URLRequest. I traced it is [object Sound] and I rechanged to .../"Music+[musicIndex]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have an error in your array access approach:

```js
myMusic.load(
    new URLRequest(
        "E:/Flash Animations/Folder 1/Games/Bit-Bot Math Voyage/Music" +
        [musicIndex] // This creates a new array with one integer element
));
```

I think you want:

```js
myMusic.load(
    new URLRequest(
        "E:/Flash Animations/Folder 1/Games/Bit-Bot Math Voyage/Music" +
        music[musicIndex] // This returns the musicIndex element from the music array
));
```

You might want a `/` at the end of `Music` too?

```js
myMusic.load(
    new URLRequest(
        "E:/Flash Animations/Folder 1/Games/Bit-Bot Math Voyage/Music/" +
        music[musicIndex] // This returns the musicIndex element from the music array
));
```

Comment: I have managed to fix the problem. But I need the music name without seeing the  ".mp3"